# How can you change the font for the contents of all tables in a document

Tags: fonts, tables, floats

Is there a simple way to set the default font for all tables in a document?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either amend the definition of `\table` directly or use the [floatrow](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package and its `\floatsetup` macro. (Note: `floatrow` by default also centers the content of floats.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\table}{\sffamily}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
(Table contents)
\end{table}

Some text outside a table.

\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{font=sf}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
(Table contents)
\end{table}

Some text outside a table.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any idea why this moves the position of the caption from the top to bottom of a table?

Answer (score 9):

The [`memoir` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) provides a means to set a default formatting for floats (if this is what you mean by "tables") via the `\setfloatadjustment{<float>}{<adjustment>}` macro. This would add `<adjustment>` to `<float>` whenever it is used. For example,

```
\setfloatadjustment{figure}{\centering}
\setfloatadjustment{table}{\small\centering}
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch certain commands/environments. By patching here, it could append code to the start/end of an environment that would change (say) the font/alignment, as in the above setup.

Comment: I've been looking at the memoir class as I'm currntly using the book class and it seems like the next step. Is it worth the leap?

Comment: I can recommend it. I've been using **memoir** for quite some time now.